# Fresh Tomcat installation works only once

Tags: java, tomcat

I have installed Tomcat 7.0.52 (also tried 8.0.3) by unpacking .tar.gz and running `bin/catalina.sh run` but it only works once.

If I stop the server by `ctrl+c` it displays shutdown informations and after returningto terminal prompt and runing it again it always hungs forever on deployin any application, for example:

`21-Mar-2014 23:42:13.818 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/tmc/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/ROOT`

Note that **this happens with 100% clean installation**, no additional webapps installed.

`netstat` don't shows tomcat port as listening after stoping, and `ps -aux` dont show any java process.

How to resolve this problem?

JDK: `openjdk-7-jdk` for amd architecture (update: same issue with oracle jdk installer)

Tested with `JAVA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` set manually and not set.

`apt-get install tomcat7` installs working Tomcat with successful restarts, but the version of Tomcat in apt-get repository is a little too low for mee (no websockets suppport). Anyway it should be possible to install manually.

Comment: What about `pgrep -lf tomcat`?

Comment: @fge no output (but pgrep command works)

Comment: Which user does it run as?

Comment: @fge root at fresh cloud server (6 core 8GB) at e24cloud.com.

Comment: Uh, DO NOT run as root :/ This is bad practice and you make processes harder to isolate... Now you can only run `pstree -uplan|less` and spot processes which may be your misbehaving servers. But create a user for Tomcat to run!

Comment: @fge I know, but if it don't want to work on root then there are even more small chances to succesfuly run on another user. (background: bought cloud machine for 2-3 hours to do some JMeter testing)

Comment: would you mind posting your catalina.out at pastebin?